# Data type calling template method

Tags: c++, templates, types

How do I use different data types without the overhead of writing a line of code for each type?

Say if there's a template method that takes any data type.
And I want to pass in various data types (int, double, string, char, ...etc) without creating a line for each data type.
Is there an efficient way of looping through different data types and call the template method for each data type??

Sample Code:

```
template <typename T>
sorted_vector<T>::sorted_vector( sorted_vector<value_type> const& rhs )
    : beg_( new value_type [rhs.size()] )
    , end_( beg_ + rhs.size() )
    , cap_( end_ )
{
    std::copy( rhs.beg_, rhs.end_, beg_ );
}
```

So my task is to test the template with bugs but wanted to check all value_types.
And I wanted to test a vector, vector, vector, etc etc

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Templates methods are build at compile time for the types you plug in. Can you give a small example as code?

Comment: Sample code that illustrates how you wish to use the template method will be useful.

Comment: I uploaded my sample code

Answer (score 1):

You may *loop* using variadic template:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void f()
    {
        // Your generic code to execute
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename F, typename ... Ts>
void Call()
{
    std::initializer_list<int>({ (F::template f<Ts>(), 0)... });
}
```

And then call it that way:

```
Call<Test, int, char, char*>();
```

But I'm not sure it is more clear than

```
// Equivalent to
Test::f<int>();
Test::f<char>();
Test::f<char*>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you are really asking as your question is too broad. I would recommend to look into `boost::variant` and especially how pattern 'visitor' is implemented there. It does not mean you have to use exactly this library, but this could be a good start point how to implement such logic. Other candidates would be `std::tuple` and `boost::any`

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a case for **Template Metaprogramming**.
Look at the *foreach* of Boost's MPL: [foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html)

Their example does something like you try to do: Calling a functor for different types and values of a list.

```
struct value_printer
{
    template< typename U > void operator()(U x)
    {
        std::cout << x << 'n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    for_each< range_c<int,0,10> >( value_printer() );
}
```